# AWS APPSYNC how to apply aws_api_key authorization

Tags: aws-amplify

How to apply @aws_api_key authorization, I applied like its said in the docs, but still getting unauthorized error

```
type Todo @aws_api_key @model
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}
```

Graphql query

```
query toTods {
  listTodos {
    items {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

gives me unauthorized error, I was able to achieve desired results by going to the APPSYNC console and editing the schema

```
type Query {
    getTodo(id: ID!): Todo
    listTodos(filter: ModelTodoFilterInput, limit: Int, nextToken: String): ModelTodoConnection
        @aws_api_key
}

type ModelTodoConnection @aws_api_key {
    items: [Todo]
    nextToken: String
}
```

But If I do a amplify push I loose all these changes. How can I specify all this in the parent Type Todo

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how you are applying this decorator in your schema?

Comment: It sounds a bit silly to ask but just want to make sure that we are on the same page. Did you declare `auth`  and `authMode` in your `AWSAppSyncClient` and `listTodos` query declaration respectively?

Comment: I am just trying it out form the aws appsync console, by selecting API_KEY for authorization

Comment: Sorry but I am a bit confused here. Are you following [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/js) tutorial?

Comment: `amplify push` is going to override your old/modified schema. So in order to specify these changes, you will have to add `auth` and `authMode` in your javascript code as mentioned in "Configure authorization modes" section of the tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, May be I am doing it all wrong, My requirement is simple. I want to  want Todo resolvers (listTodos) to be acessebile/authorized through aws_api_keys

Comment: But you have mentioned that you were able to achieve this my modifying your schema in your AppSync console?

Comment: I was doing it wrong, I got it, it has to be set using the @auth directive, but now I have another issue with the amplify/cli not updating apiKey realted to this https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3802

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you running a lambda in background and that lambda is calling some appssync API so you can apply @aws_api_key in type of response return by that graphql API. this give access to that lambda to call that graphql API.
eg;

```
type Myclass @aws_api_key {
id: ID!
name: String
students: [Student]
batch: Int
}

extend type Mutation {
   getClass(id: Int!): Myclass @aws_api_key
} 

extend type Subscription {
onGetClass: Myclass @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["getClass"])
}
```

AWS API key is one of the authorization method through which we can call grahql API. This way help us to make some API called though API gateway and some to call through access token(from aws cognito or auth0,etc).This avoid case of creating new repo for open API(which best work for guest users)